# Reading certain strings from text file and outputing them to a TextBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to programming to Visual Basic using Visual Studio 2013 and I cannot figure out how to pull the elements of what I want out of a text file I am reading in. I am able to pull in the entire text file with my code below, but I do not need to the entire text file. I only need two things from it to output to a field I define in a TextBox.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub BrowseBtn2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BrowseBtn2.Click
        OpenFileDialog2.ShowDialog()
        FilePathLabel2.Text = OpenFileDialog2.FileName
    End Sub

    Private Sub GenerateBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GenerateBtn.Click

        Dim FILE_NAME As String = OpenFileDialog2.FileName
        Dim TextLine As String

        If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog2.FileName)

            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                TextLine = TextLine & objReader.ReadLine() & vbNewLine
            Loop
            TextBox1.Text = TextLine
        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub CloseBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseBtn.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Text file looks like this:

```
**

*Header

**
* YYY Vendor: MY

*

Customer: My Wifi

Quantity: 10

Type: 3456778

Profile: NNNN-1

Batch: 0123

*

UMTS Transport_key: 0

IMS Transport_key: 000

*

Address1:

Address2:

Address3:

Address4:

*

Graph_ref:

PO_ref_number:

*

*

*

*

Network Selection Parameters Input File (NSPIF) Version: 00.00.0000

*

GSM SMSC Address: 18001234567

Email Gateway address: 000

*

*

*

*

**

*Input Vars

**

var_in_list:

IMSI:310000000000001

Ser_nb:89010000000000000001

IMPI:310111111111111@private.net

IMPU:310111111111111@one.net

**

*Output Variables

**

var_out: PIN1/PUK1/PIN2/PUK2/K_UMTS/K_IMS/ADM1/Access_Control/DL_Key

310000000000001 89010000000000000001 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000002 89010000000000000002 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000003 89010000000000000003 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000004 89010000000000000004 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000005 89010000000000000005 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000006 89010000000000000006 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000007 89010000000000000007 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000008 89010000000000000008 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000009 89010000000000000009 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
310000000000010 89010000000000000010 2222 11111111 3333 22222222 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF 1111111111111111 0000 00112233445566778899AABBCCDDEEFF
```

All I want is the string "89010000000000000001" from the first line that starts with "310000000000001" and the string "89010000000000000010" from the last line that starts with "310000000000010"

How should I go about getting those two strings?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by storing the line in a variable

```
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    Dim curLine As String = objReader.ReadLine()
    TextLine = TextLine & curLine & vbNewLine
Loop
```

Then only print the lines that starts with 310000000000001

```
Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    Dim curLine As String = objReader.ReadLine()

    If curLine.StartsWith("310000000000001") Then
        TextLine = TextLine & curLine & vbNewLine
    End If
Loop
```

You can then store the first and last line and print them at the end of the process

```
Dim startLine, endLine As String

startLine = ""
endLine = ""

Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
    Dim curLine As String = objReader.ReadLine()

    If curLine.StartsWith("310000000000001") Then
        If startLine = "" Then
            startLine = curLine
        End If

        endLine = curLine
    End If
Loop

TextLine = TextLine & startLine & vbNewLine
TextLine = TextLine & endLine & vbNewLine
```

With a simple Split you can get the second item of the line.

```
TextLine = TextLine & startLine.Split(" ")(1) & vbNewLine
TextLine = TextLine & endLine.Split(" ")(1) & vbNewLine
```